# Is there any new improvement in the proof or disproof of the twin prime conjucture?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I think this is not the first question about twin primes here, but my own is the latest one!

I  am a postgraduate student in Mathematics interested in the field of number theory. While searching on net I found out that the ***twin prime problem*** is one of the unsolved problem in Number theory. As a kid in mathematics research, I feel I can write something about it. (I do not mean that I will solve the problem, but I will try).

So, is there any new improvement in the proof or disproof of the twin prime conjucture?.

Thanks.

Comment: New improvement since when?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: From the beginning of 2012.

Comment: @anon: Thanks, I have fix it.

Comment: As a postgraduate student in Mathematics, you have access to the faculty at your institution. If there is someone there who works in Number Theory, she is the perfect person to answer your question. She may not know the answer offhand, but it's part of her job to either answer it for you or to show you how to find the answer yourself. And if there is no one in your department working in Number Theory, then you aren't going to work on the twin prime problem there: better find a different place to study, if that's what you want to work on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, there is no one studying number theory in our department. May be I will think of another area.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be too late to be useful to you, and you've likely heard the news from another source, but: Yes! There has been!

Here's the most recent update from the polymath project by Terence Tao:
http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/bounded-gaps-between-primes-polymath8-a-progress-report/

And here's a round-up of post about the result by Evelyn Lamb:
http://blogs.ams.org/blogonmathblogs/2013/05/16/week-in-number-theory/